Error opening sound device: Unable to find default audio device (PJMEDIA_EAUD_NODEFDEV) [status=420006]
hey i have created my own sip server in python using the pjsip at work good but i want this to record the customer call voice and save and it show me this error please can anyone help me with this Error retrieving default audio device parameters:
Unable to find default audio device (PJMEDIA_EAUD_NODEFDEV) [status=420006]
15:01:23.334 pjsua_aud.c ....Error opening sound device: Unable to find default audio device (PJMEDIA_EAUD_NODEFDEV) [status=420006]
15:01:23.334 media.cpp ...pjsua_conf_connect(id, sink.id) error: Unable to find default audio device (PJMEDIA_EAUD_NODEFDEV) (status=420006) [../src/pjsua2/media.cpp:218]
ERROR:main:Error connecting media to recorder:

i want to record the customer voice on call and save it in .wav extension i am running my server in azure vm which do not have any audio setup and device and i am using the pisip2.14.1 library
